# Is any CFL  intersection,union of CFLs that are not inherently ambiguous?

Tags: formal-languages

Is any CFL  intersection,union of CFLs that are not inherently ambiguous?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "inherently ambiguous"? 

Comment: @David,inherently ambiguouse means there is no unambiguous grammar that generates the language,you know some grammars may generate a word in several different ways.